# How to determine that the form submitted has more than one element with same name

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, httprequest

The JSP from which I receive the request may have more then one form element with same name(Group of Checkbox with same name). At such time when we call `request.getParameterValues()` instead of `request.getParameter()`, We will get a array of values that corresponds to the form element with same name. How to determine which method to call.

How to determine from Servlet side that the submitted form has element with same name and which parameter name correspond to that form element.

It is important for me to determine which element are multiple with same name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always call `request.getParameterValues()`. It returns array of values. If array contains only one element there were only one field of that name.

Comment: This can be one way for me but suppose I have a group if checkboxes with same name and the client only check one box. At such time I can't efficiently determine the above.

Comment: In that case, you should have different values in each of the checkboxes. Calling 'request.getParameterValues()' as suggested by AlexR, will return the vaues of the checked ones.